# Microsoft SQL Server Query is Returning Wrong Result

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
$GetUID = $c->query("SELECT UserUID FROM dbo.Users_Master ORDER BY UserID DESC");
$UserUniqueID = $GetUID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$UUID = $UserUniqueID['UserUID'];
$NewUUID = $UUID + 1;
```

This is successfully working, but the problem is something with my query.

It is always entering 12 into my database.

I went to the Microsoft SQL query window and entered:

```
USE UserData;
SELECT UserUID FROM dbo.Users_Master ORDER BY UserID DESC
```

and it returned:

> 11, 17, 15, 19, 16, 18, 10, 13, 12, 14, 3

Which is not exactly ordering by the highest to lowest.

I then went on using:

```
USE UserData;
SELECT UserUID FROM dbo.Users_Master ORDER BY UserID ASC
```

Which returned:

> 3, 14, 12, 13, 10, 18, 16, 19, 15, 17, 11

I want to obtain the higest UserUID and +1 to it.. WHy is my code selecting *11* all the time?

Comment: What data type is `UserID`? Is it `INT` or something else?

Comment: You are selecting UserUID and set order to UserID  ? UserID = UserUID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `UserId` is not of the datatype `int`, you can `cast()` the value to order:

```
SELECT UserUID 
FROM dbo.Users_Master 
ORDER BY cast(UserID as int) DESC
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17873/2)

However, the best solution is to alter the datatype in the table to match what is being stored.

To alter the table in SQL Server, you would use:

```
alter table dbo.Users_Master alter column UserID int;
```

This would store the data in the correct datatype so you would not have to `cast()` the value to order it.

Edit #1, based on your comment that `UserId` is a varchar it seems like you mean to `ORDER BY UserUID DESC` which is an `int`

Comment: `Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BravoSlayer' to data type int.`

Comment: @user1968541 is `BravoSlayer` the same field as `UserID`?

Comment: I have two columns, UserUID which is INT then UserID which is varchar

Comment: @user1968541 in your OP you were requesting `ORDER BY UserID DESC` which if that is a `varchar` then you cannot cast that as an `int`. It sounds like you want to use `ORDER BY UserUID DESC`

Comment: That was the problem then! sorry for wastin' your time

Comment: @user1968541 glad you figured it out. :)